# Use same header across all views

Tags: swift, xcode

Swift/Xcode newbie here.

I'm making an app for my [website](https://www.flashkase.com).

I have a header on my app. I'd like keep the same header for 4 view controllers and hide it for 1 view controllers

Examples. The first 3 have the desired header, and the 4th one has a different header. I'm trying to replicate this in xcode-swift

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

If something is unclear, please state what is unclear.

Also, a great example of what I'd like to do is this very app

Comment: Explain what you have tried and why you feel you weren't able to accomplish your goal. That might help engender a positive response to your question.

Comment: I would suggest to create a BaseviewController class and add this top view in that, now all other viewcontrollers can subclass this and have this added. Another approach can be, have a viewcontroller added this view on top, and add all other viewcotnroller as childViewController to this.

Comment: @Aks thank you so much aks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:-

1. Using Parent-ChildViewController, Creating a ViewController with headerView at top and a containerView. Now you can just add your other viewController in this containerView (childViewController).
2. Using a BaseViewController which have this top header view and then subclassing your view controller on it.